# Node bot to send out reminder emails for forgotten employee weekly schedule submissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babel.js

This `CalendarService` is part of a little node-bot I wrote today which sends out reminder-emails if a team member forgets to submit his weekly schedule in time. Calendar backend is using Google Calendar.

I'm interested in feedback, what I could simplify, where are the code smells, etc.

**index.js**

```
import CalendarService from './calendarService';
import MailService from './mailService';
import TeamService from './teamService';

const mailService = new MailService();
const calendarService = new CalendarService();
const teamService = new TeamService();

console.log('Loading calendar credentials…');
calendarService.loadCredentials()

.then((credentials) => {
  console.log('✓ Credentials loaded');
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
  console.log('Authorizing with Google API…');

  return calendarService.authorize(credentials);
})

.then(() => {
  console.log('✓ Google API authorized');
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
  console.log('Fetching calendar events for current week…');

  return calendarService.listEventsForUpcomingWeek();
})

.then((events) => {
  console.log('✓ Events fetched');
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
  console.log('Identifying missing dates…');
  const missingDatesPerTeamMember = [];

  teamService.getTeam().forEach((teamMember) => {
    const teamMemberEvents = events.filter((event) => event.creator.email === teamMember.email);
    const missingDates = calendarService.identifyMissingDates(teamMemberEvents);
    if (missingDates.length) {
      missingDatesPerTeamMember.push({ teamMember: teamMember, missingDates: missingDates });
    }
  });

  return missingDatesPerTeamMember;
})

.then((missingDates) => {
  console.log('✓ Missing dates identified');
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
  console.log('Sending out emails to team members with missing dates…');

  return mailService.sendEmailsToTeamMembersWithMissingDates(missingDates);
})

.then(() => {
  console.log('✓ Emails are out');
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
  console.log('✓ All done!');
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
})

.catch((error) => {
  console.log('------------------------------------------');
  console.error('An error occurred:', error);
});
```

**calendarService.js**

```
import fs from 'fs';
import config from './config';
import readline from 'readline';
import google from 'googleapis';
import GoogleAuth from 'google-auth-library';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-range';

class CalendarService {
  loadCredentials() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
          reject('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
          return;
        }
        resolve(JSON.parse(content));
      });
    });
  }

  /**
  * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials
  *
  * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
  */
  authorize(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
      const clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
      const redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
      const auth = new GoogleAuth();
      this.oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

      // Check if we have previously stored a token.
      fs.readFile(config.tokenPath, (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
          this.getNewToken(this.oauth2Client)
            .then(newToken => resolve(newToken))
            .catch(error => reject('Could not get token:', error));
        } else {
          this.oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
          resolve(token);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  /**
  * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
  * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
  *
  * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
  */
  getNewToken(oauth2Client) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        'access_type': 'offline',
        scope: config.calendarScopes
      });
      console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
      const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
      });
      rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            reject('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            return;
          }
          oauth2Client.credentials = token;
          this.storeToken(token);
          resolve(token);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  /**
  * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
  *
  * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
  */
  storeToken(token) {
    try {
      fs.mkdirSync(config.tokenDir);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
        throw err;
      }
    }
    fs.writeFile(config.tokenPath, JSON.stringify(token));
    console.log('Token stored to ' + config.tokenPath);
  }

  /**
  * Lists all events for the current workweek (monday-friday) from the team calendar
  */
  listEventsForUpcomingWeek() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
      const weekStart = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(1)._d;
      const weekEnd   = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(5)._d;
      calendar.events.list({
        auth: this.oauth2Client,
        calendarId: config.calendarEndpoint,
        timeMin: weekStart.toISOString(),
        timeMax: weekEnd.toISOString(),
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
      }, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          reject('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        }

        const events = response.items;

        if (events.length === 0) {
          resolve('No upcoming events found.');
        }

        resolve(events);
      });
    });
  }

  getWeekRange() {
    const startOfNextWeek = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(1).startOf('day');
    const endOfNextWeek   = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(5).startOf('day');
    const weekRange = moment.range(startOfNextWeek, endOfNextWeek);
    return weekRange;
  }

  identifyMissingDates(events) {
    const transformedEvents = events.map(this._transformCalendarEventsIntoMomentJsRange);
    const weekRange = this.getWeekRange();
    const missingDates = [];

    weekRange.by('days', (day) => {
      const match = transformedEvents.filter((event) => day.within(event));
      if (!match.length) {
        missingDates.push(day._d.toString());
      }
    });

    return missingDates;
  }

  _transformCalendarEventsIntoMomentJsRange(event) {
    const start = moment(event.start.date).startOf('day');
    const end = moment(event.end.date).startOf('day');
    return moment.range(start, end);
  }
}

export default CalendarService;
```

**mailService.js**

```
import config from './config';
import fs from 'fs';
import postmark from 'postmark';

class MailService {
  constructor() {
    this.postmarkClient = new postmark.Client(config.postmarkApiKey);
  }

  sendEmailsToTeamMembersWithMissingDates(results) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const messages = results.map((result) => {
        const name = result.teamMember.name.split(' ')[0] || result.teamMember.name;
        const email = this.composeEmail(name, result.missingDates);
        return email;
      });

      this.postmarkClient.sendEmailBatch(messages, (error, success) => {
        if (error) {
          reject('Unable to send mail via postmark: ' + error.message);
          return;
        }
        resolve(`Sent emails out to postmark`);
      });
    });
  }

  composeEmail(name, missingDates) {
    const missingDatesString = missingDates.map((date) => {
      return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() + '\n\t';
    }).join('');

    return {
      "From": "xxx@xxx.com",
      "To": "xxx@xxx.com",
      "Subject": "Missing Dates in Team Calendar for this week",
      "TextBody": `
        Hey ${name},

        friendly reminder to fill in your dates for the team calendar this week.
        My minions tell me that the following dates are stil missing:

        ${missingDatesString}

        Sincerely,
        Nudge Bot

      `,
      "Attachments": [{
        "Content": fs.readFileSync("./minions.jpg").toString('base64'),
        "Name": "minions.jpg",
        "ContentType": "image/jpeg"
      }]
    };
  }
}

export default MailService;
```

**teamService.js**

```
import fs from 'fs';

class TeamService {
  constructor() {
    fs.readFile('team.json', (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading team file: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      this.team = JSON.parse(content);
    });
  }

  getTeam() {
    return this.team;
  }
}

export default TeamService;
```

Comment: As an aside I would *strongly* recommend precompiling your code with babel and running it with node - rather than running through babel-node - simply due to the perf impact. If this is run as a cron job, it will have to be transpiled every time you run it which will increase the time it takes to run the program by a decent chunk.

Answer (score 2):

A few things I can spot, in no particular order:

- As [Dan Pantry suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111789/node-bot-to-send-out-reminder-emails-if-a-team-member-doesnt-submit-their-weekl#comment206260_111789), it's probably better if you precompile your files using babel (i.e. add a build step) and run it normally with node. Normally there wouldn't be an issue, but if run in a cron multiple times, the penalty can stack up.
- DRY: `const cl = console.log.bind(console)`
- In some of the cases, you're using the normal version (`readFile()` and in some, you're using the sync version (`readFileSync()`), in a CLI, there's nothing wrong with using sync operations. But pick one and stay consistent.
- Always `reject()` with an instance of `Error`. Just like you should always `throw` and instance of `Error`.
- Don't nest `.then()` inside of a Promise constructor or other `.then()`s. Chain promises by returning. (i.e. `new Promise(...).then()` and not `new Promise(... .then() ...)`).
- Be consistent with your naming convention. I sometimes see `error` and sometimes `err`.
- Have a look into `async` functions and `await`.
- If you only have one statement, an arrow function can be shortened from `(param) => { return doSomethingWith(param); }` to `(param) => doSomethingWith(param);` to `param => doSomethingWith(param);`.
- Promise constructors should generally be used at the *lowest possible level*. Promisify all of the callback-based functions, and construct functions on top of those Promise-returning functions.
- `class Foo {} export default Foo` can be shortened to `export default class Foo {}`.
- `{foo: foo, bar: bar}` can be shortened to `{foo, bar}`.
- Your `storeToken()` method has absolutely no guarantee of success. (`writeFile` is async, and you're returning before it's done, you don't know if it failed or not).
- Stay consistent with your object key naming and quoting.